# boost::asio::io_service async_write in loop while doing an async_read

Tags: c++, boost-asio, tcpserver

So my problem is the following I have an async TCP server and the respective async client. What I need is a way to be able to write to my client (continuously), a real time variable, while at the same time being able to receive commands from the client.

What I have right now is, if the client send the command that should trigger this operations it sends just a test message but I'm only finding a way to send one message because after that the server hangs waiting for a client command.

This function is the one that handles the commands sent from the client and after receiving passes them to the function h_read:

```
void conn::h_write()   {
    memset( data_, '\0', sizeof(char)*max_length );
    async_read_until(sock_ , input_buffer_, '\n',
    boost::bind(&conn::h_read, shared_from_this()));

}
```

Here I check if the command is the one that should trigger continuously write of the real time buffer to the client, in this case the command is "c".

```
void conn::h_read(){
    std::string line;
    std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
    std::getline(is, line);
    std::string output = "";
    output.reserve(5000);
    if ( line == "exit"){
        return;
    }
    if ( line.empty() ){
        memset( data_, '\0', sizeof(char)*max_length );
        async_read_until(sock_ , input_buffer_, '\n', boost::bind(&conn::h_read, shared_from_this()));
        return;
    }

    clientMessage_ = line;      
    clientMessage_ += '\n';

    if ( clientMessage_.substr(0,1) == "c" ){
        std::stringstream toSend;
        streamON = true;
        toSend.str("c l 1 ");
        toSend << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 2 ) << luxID1[0];
        toSend.str(" ");
        // Here I sent the real time value for the first time
        boost::asio::async_write(sock_, boost::asio::buffer( toSend.str() ), boost::bind(&conn::sendRealTime, shared_from_this()));
    }       
    else{ // Does't really matter to this example
        // Do some stuff here and send to client
        boost::asio::async_write(sock_, boost::asio::buffer( I2CrxBuf_ ), boost::bind(&conn::h_write, shared_from_this()));
    }
}
```

Now this is the function that should handle the continuous send of the variable but at the same time be able to read the client commands:

```
void conn::sendRealTime(){
    if ( streamON ){
        boost::asio::async_write(sock_, boost::asio::buffer( "This is a test\n" ), boost::bind(&conn::h_write, shared_from_this()));
        memset( data_, '\0', sizeof(char)*max_length );
        async_read_until(sock_ , input_buffer_, '\n', boost::bind(&conn::h_read, shared_from_this()));
    }
    else{
        memset( data_, '\0', sizeof(char)*max_length );
        async_read_until(sock_ , input_buffer_, '\n', boost::bind(&conn::h_read, shared_from_this()));
    }
}
```

The problem is that it blocks after the first call to the "async_read_util" functions.

I don't even know if what I want is even possible, but if it is could someone please help me on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need is a way to be able to write to my client (continuously),
>   a real time variable, while at the same time being able to receive
>   commands from the client.

This is not a problem.

Separate your read and write functions. Call [`async_read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html) once after the socket was successfully connected / initialized. Then in your read-handler call it again. Nowhere else. This is the usual way of performing read operations.

Please also refer to the [documentation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html)

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read
>   operations (such as async_read, async_read_until, the stream's
>   async_read_some function, or any other composed operations that
>   perform reads) until this operation completes.

Remember that the data in the read-buffer may contain more than you expect it to be.

> After a successful async_read_until operation, the streambuf may
>   contain additional data beyond the delimiter. An application will
>   typically leave that data in the streambuf for a subsequent
>   async_read_until operation to examine.